# Generic method for finding instances of classes with 'is' operator

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin development and trying to create a function that takes an instance of a Exception and a class (e.g RuntimeException) to check if the instance is an instance of the specific class, in Kotlin. The idea is that you have caught a specific type of exception. You then want to traverse up the causes of this exception until you have the specific exception that you were looking for.

```
        fun findExceptionType(currentException : Throwable?, exceptionToFind: KClass<Throwable>): Throwable? {
            var _currentException = currentException
            while((_currentException!!.cause == null)!!) {
                if (_currentException is exceptionToFind) {
                    return _currentException.cause
                }
                _currentException = _currentException.cause
            }
            return null
        }
```

The idea is that it will keep traversing up the `exception.cause` until either the `exception.cause` is null, or you have found the type of exception that you were searching for. This seems like something that would already have been implemented and so I'm surprised I'm having to implement this myself.

The reason for this utility function is to avoid having to traverse up all the `exception.cause`s until you find the specific type that you need.

To be more specific:

In Kotlin there is an 'is' operator, for instance you can say `if (s is String)`, however in my function above I want to make it generic by having something like `if (s is X)` where `X` is passed into the function. What would be the type of `X`? At the moment I've used `KClass` but I'm not sure what the type signature of the `is` operator is?

Comment: Note, you shouldn't use the `!!` operator here, otherwise it'll throw a `NullPointerException`. Use `?.` instead, as in `_currentException?.cause` to perform null-safe member traversal.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also learning about the whole `!!` and `?.` notations.

Comment: I've never used them myself, but, if I'm right, reified parameters exist exactly for such cases: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @dyukha. It's pretty convenient to use `reified` type parameters here. With it you can rewrite your function like:

```
inline fun <reified T : Throwable> findExceptionType(throwable: Throwable?): T? {
    var error = throwable
    while (error !is T) {
        error = error?.cause
    }
    return error
}
```

As generic `if (s is X) where X is passed into the function` you can use something like this:

```
(x as? String)?.let { println(it) }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I hadn't actually heard of 'reification' so wasn't even sure how to search for this. Now that I know the keyword I've found the documentation. Much appreciate the help :)

Comment: `(x as? String)?.let(::println)` because function references ;-)